# Adding button to GameScene.swift programatically and transitioning scenes when pressed

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I have been working forever trying to implement a way to add a button and when pressed the scene transitions to my second view. I have read other posts but have had ZERO luck for something in Swift 3. I'm really confused and have tried but failed many times. Hope you can help! Thanks!

Swift 3 in SpriteKit.

Comment: share what you've tried so far please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you mean transition to a new view?. When making SpriteKit games we tend to transition between SKScenes and not views. So do not try to create different views or viewControllers for each scene, just transition between SKScenes directly.

In regards to buttons, there is plenty tutorials available. You basically create a SKSpriteNode as a button and look for it in touchesBegan and do something when its pressed.

This is a simple example here

https://nathandemick.com/2014/09/buttons-sprite-kit-using-swift/

Essential you can create a button subclass similar to this.

```
class Button: SKNode {
      let defaultButton: SKSpriteNode
      let activeButton: SKSpriteNode
      var action: () -> ()

      init(defaultButtonImage: String, activeButtonImage: String, buttonAction: @escaping () -> ()) {
           defaultButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: defaultButtonImage)
           activeButton = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: activeButtonImage)
           activeButton.isHidden = true
           action = buttonAction

           super.init()

           isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           addChild(defaultButton)
           addChild(activeButton)
     }

     required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
           fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
     }

     override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        activeButton.isHidden = false
        defaultButton.isHidden = true
     }

     override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        for touch in touches {
             let location = touch.location(in: self)

             if defaultButton.contains(location) {
                  activeButton.isHidden = false
                  defaultButton.isHidden = true
             } else {
                   activeButton.isHidden = true
                   defaultButton.isHidden = false
             } 
        }
     }

     override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
          for touch in touches {
             let location = touch.location(in: self)

             if defaultButton.contains(location) {
                 action()
             }

             activeButton.isHidden = true
             defaultButton.isHidden = false
         }
    }
}
```

and than in your relevant SKScene add your buttons

```
 class StartScene: SKScene {

      override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

          let playButton = Button(defaultButtonImage: "button", activeButtonImage: "button_active", buttonAction: loadGameScene)
           playButton.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY)
           addChild(playButton)
      }

      func loadGameScene() {
          let scene = GameScene(...)
          let transition = SKTransition....
          scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill
          view?.presentScene(scene, transition: transition)
      }
 }
```

You can also check out Apples sample game DemoBots for another button class example using protocols.

Hope this helps

Comment: Hi crashoverride777, please add some code to your answer because links could become unavailable during time and because I want to upvote your answer :-)

Comment: Thanks, just updating the sytanx to swift 3 as it was an older tutorial

Comment: @crashoverride777 Only error I'm having is in the second block of code you had provided. let playButton = Button(defaultButtonImage: "button", activeButtonImage: "button_active", buttonAction: loadGameScene) I'm getting an error "use of unresolved identifier" not sure why.

Comment: I edited the comment. The error is: "use of unresolved identifier" So I put your first block of code in the Button class like you said. Now your second block of code is in my first scene, when I put it in my FirstScene class I get the error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129299/discussion-between-r-khaira-and-crashoverride777).

Comment: You need to add this code in didMove to view. Check my updated answer of how your start scene can look.

Comment: hmm, weird. That part works now, so thanks for that. But now back to the first part of the code "class Button: SKNode" Is this class put in the GameViewController.swift or the GameScene.swift? Because right now ALL the code you gave me is in my GameScene.swift with its corresponding class. My question: Is the Button class put in the GameViewCont.swift or GameScene.swift?

Comment: Button class is supposed to be in a extra swift file. It's independent of game scene.